# Angularjs $scope value is not updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

Okay i have the following HTML:

```
<timer countdown="30" interval="1000">
{{seconds}}
percent
</timer>
{{timerSeconds}}
```

For this i have the following controller code:

```
$scope.timerRunning = true;
$scope.timerSeconds = 100;
$scope.$on('timer-tick',function(e, val) {
    $scope.timerSeconds = (Math.floor(val.millis / 1000) / 30 * 100);
});
```

However the view `timerSeconds` is not updated. I verified the event by debugging and found that it is executing the function and changing `timerSeconds` value.

Comment: Adding more code could help us see what is happening. Could you please create a plnkr/jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after this line:

```
$scope.timerSeconds = (Math.floor(val.millis / 1000) / 30 * 100);
```

add

```
$scope.apply();
```

So that AngularJS check if there is changes in models and rerender them.

In many cases AngularJS can't dected a model change, especially in an **Asynch** functions like `$on()`

read more about it: [When to use $scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply%28%29)

If it dosn't work, use AngularJS $timeout function

```
$scope.$on('timer-tick',function(e, val) {
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.timerSeconds = (Math.floor(val.millis / 1000) / 30 * 100);
    })
});
```

Comment: wrap your $scope.timerSeconds = (Math.floor(val.millis / 1000) / 30 * 100);  in $timeout callback and try again, (remove $scope.$apply())

Comment: can you post your change to your question?

Comment: $on is an angular method, I think it will always call apply() no?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen, I used the AngularJS $timeout function to solve your problem, I have updated my answer

Comment: @Sn0opr not sure what you mean, I'm pretty sure $apply at the end of the $on block is redundant

Comment: @Sn0opr when i run this i get: $timeout is not defined

Comment: LoL stupid me forgot to inject it into my controller this worked thanks!